# how to get form elements values in javascript and create a url with thoese values

Tags: php, javascript, forms

For example I have a form:

```
<form name='myform' id='myformid'>

  <input type='text' name='name' id='name'>
  <input type='text' name='color' id='color'>
  <input type='text' name='made' id='made'>

  <input type='submit' name='submit'>

</form>
```

Now I want to call a javascript function on above form submit. This function will get all form elements values and create a URL to redirect.

For example:

```
example.com/search.php?name=toyota&color=white&made=abc
```

How can I create this JS function?

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to do this with JavaScript, if the form tag can deliver all you need? Do you want to validate the contents?

Comment: I need this. I want to know this. You don't know where will I use this. You don't know what point I want to learn. I write a simple question with simple example to get answer. Anyway thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Awan — As a rule of thumb, if someone doesn't know how to do something then there is a good chance that they aren't in a good position to judge if they *should* do the something. Throwing a "Don't question me!" rant at people trying to help you is going to reflect badly on you and throw away the opportunity to get suggestions about how better to solve [the real problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getValues(){
  var form = document.getElementById('myformid');
  var url  = 'example.com/search.php?';

  for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++) {
     var element = form.elements[i];
     //url += (i>0 ? '&' : '') + element.name + '=' + element.value;
     //UPDATE
     url += (i>0 ? '&' : '') + encodeURIComponent(element.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(element.value);
  }
  return url;
}
```

Comment: Don't try to build URIs by just smashing together arbitary strings. [encode them properly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: You are right, encodeURIComponent(value) should be sufficient IMHO

Comment: You need to encode the names too (at least in the general case).

Comment: I have a problem. My actual form has some dropdowns. It is writing **Array** for those elements in URL. How to solve this.. Any solution ??

Comment: It is giving me result something like this `?Array=toyota&Array=red&Array=abc`

Comment: @Awan: it should work with it. (<select name='mySelect'><option value='opt1'>opt1</option></select>)

Comment: But it is giving me this result with form with even all textboxes.

`?Array=toyota&Array=red&Array=abc`

Comment: @Awan so there must be a problem in the rest of your code. What browser are you actually using? I have tested this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2kbqE/) on Firefox/Chrome/IE and it works.

Comment: I am using google chrome. Ok. It is working on jsfiddle.net. I check my code. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

With the MochiKit library you could use:

http://mochi.github.com/mochikit/doc/html/MochiKit/DOM.html#fn-formcontents

Source here:

https://github.com/mochi/mochikit/blob/master/MochiKit/DOM.js#L45

This along with the 'querystring' function from the same library:

http://mochi.github.com/mochikit/doc/html/MochiKit/Base.html#fn-querystring

https://github.com/mochi/mochikit/blob/master/MochiKit/Base.js#L1184

And you can have a simple solution:

```
window.location.href = 'example.com/search.php?' + queryString(formContents(getElement('myformid')))
```

Comment: I cant use any library. I need simple javascript. Thanks

Comment: I understand. Just note that e.g. MochiKit takes care of browsers where encodeURIComponent isn't defined.

Comment: JavaScript is simpler when you let someone else package up all the complicated parts in a library.

Comment: @EoghanM — What browsers which don't support encodeURIComponent are of concern these days? (Or even 5 years ago)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I know using a library is useful. Even this is easy for me to do in jQuery but its customer choice. So there are always some problems when your customer is also technical..

Comment: *encodeURIComponent* was in ECMA-262 ed 3, so 12 years old. Any browser so old as to not support it would be utterly useless on the web today.

Answer (score 1):

I know you want a **javascript** function, **but** this way maybe better if you want to send your request after submit:

```
<form name='myform' action='search.php' method='get'>
  <input type='text' name='name' />
  <input type='text' name='color' />
  <input type='text' name='made' />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: Why the XML-style markup? If you want valid markup, you also need a block element inside the form to wrap the form controls. But browsers will tolerate its absence.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

function myFunction() {
    var name=document.myform.name.value;
    var color=document.myform.color.value;
    var made=document.myform.made.value;

    alert('example.com/search.php?name='+name+'&color='+color+'&made='+made);

}

</script>

<form name='myform' id='myformid' onSubmit='javascript:myFunction()'>

  <input type='text' name='name' id='name'>
  <input type='text' name='color' id='color'>
  <input type='text' name='made' id='made'>

  <input type='submit' name='submit'>

</form>
```

Comment: Why have you got a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#label_Statement) named `javascript:` in there? It isn't doing anything.

Comment: And you've failed to escape the data you are smashing together into a URL.